# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am upgrading a `spring mvc` app to `hibernate 4.3.7` and `JPA 2.1` from `hibernate 4.2` and `JPA 2.0`.  My `eclipse` project uses the `eclipse maven m2e plugin`.  Somehow, when I changed the version number of `hibernate` in the `pom.xml` and added a `jpa 2.1` dependency, my app stopped compiling and gives the following error instead:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
```

I then added the following to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But my app still will not compile, and still gives the same error.  Oddly enough, the compilation error even persists when I toggle the old versions of `hibernate` and `JPA` and do a `maven.. update project` in `eclipse`.  I have never encountered this error before today.  **How can I resolve this error?**

You can read the complete `pom.xml` [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/EwQ3No9N0LhVNhMjLylv?b=VzZyLUZBAUL78cFYwtyP).

The stack trace when I try to `Run As..Run on Server` in eclipse is:

```
Nov 07, 2014 11:47:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildHibernateConfiguration(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1031)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Have you tried 4.3.6 version of Hibernate in POM ?

Comment: could you provide your complete pom.xml please ?

Comment: @Pracede There is a link to the complete pom.xml in my posting above.  Here is the same link again:  https://jumpshare.com/v/EwQ3No9N0LhVNhMjLylv?b=VzZyLUZBAUL78cFYwtyP

Comment: @kulatamicuda Thank you.  I just tried 4.3.6 version of hibernate but get the same error.

Comment: @CodeMed strange, I have using 4.3.6 together with dom4j 1.6.1 myself and it simply works. Try using spring BOM and spring boot parent project - it manages all versions automatically. See their  spring-boot-starter-data-jpa , with spring boot version 1.1.8.

Comment: @kulatamicuda I just added the following to my `pom.xml`, did a `maven update` in `eclipse`, then tried to relaunch the app and the server, but got the same compile error.  Is this what you meant?  Here is the link: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.1.8.RELEASE

Comment: @kulatamicuda I used the windows command line to run `mvn dependency:tree` on the root folder of the project.  Would that help you diagnose the problem?  Here is the link: https://jumpshare.com/v/7kvkRe2C3XCLmG05UZSW?b=nanZ1tEqx82aLoKhHGhA

Comment: Look here http://start.spring.io/ , generate jdbc and JPA maven project and see what dependencies it created in effective Pom.

Comment: @kulatamicuda thank you.  I tried the link and will spend more time with it later when I am able to do so.  But at first glance I notice that hibernate is not included in the options, and I wonder if this problem is generated by hibernate upgrade issues.  But I will examine it more closely when I have time later.

Comment: @CodeMed hibernate is jpa option as hibernate is spring boot default jpa 2.1 provider. Just use Spring boot 1.1.8 from menu and it will configure maven Pom for hibernate 4.3.6. + spring 4.0.7.